# Whenever I print the 16 Pen Trend at Run Time its background colour changes from White to Black

Tags: wonderware

I am working on Schneider Electric WonderWare InTouch 10.5 version.
I am using 16 Pen Trend to see the historical values, but when at run time I print this trend, the background colour of trend changes from White to Black.

Following is the script I am using for the printing purpose :
PrintWindow("report1",0,0,11.7,7.9,1);

Following is the Syntax for above function :
PrintWindow (windowname, leftmargin, topmargin, width, height, options);

**Parameters**

*windowname*

The name of the window to be printed. A literal string value, message tagname, or string expression.

*leftmargin*

Left margin offset (in inches). A literal numeric value, analog tagname, or numeric expression.

*topmargin*

Top margin offset (in inches). A literal numeric value, analog tagname, or numeric expression.

*width*

Printout width (in inches). Set this value to 0 for largest aspect ratio. A literal numeric value, analog tagname, or numeric expression.

*height*

Printout height (in inches). Set this value to 0 for largest aspect ratio. A literal numeric value, analog tagname, or numeric expression.

*options*

A discrete value, 0 or 1, that is only used if width and height are 0. A literal Boolean value, discrete tagname or Boolean expression. Set to:

1 - The window is printed with the largest aspect ratio that is an integer multiple of the window size.

0 - The window is printed with the largest aspect ratio that fits on the page.

If any knowledge about it, please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you doing this with an ArchestrA graphic or an ActiveX control? I launched a v10.6 VM that I have but I'm not sure what Trend you're printing with to try it out myself.

Comment: I am using the 16 pen trend that comes included with InTouch 10.5 Package.